# How do I scroll to the right on a page that overflows horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll to the far right edge of a page that is really wide (it's wide on purpose) when the user closes a modal (specifically, the Reveal modal in Foundation 4).

I've tried setting an id on a div that's aligned all the way right, but that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Well this was answered elsewhere on the internet more precisely than I could answer it: [http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To scroll horizontally, you use [scrollLeft()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/).

```
$('body, html').scrollLeft(400);
```

jQuery also supports animating the `scrollLeft` property.

To scroll all the way to the right, you get the full width of the page, and subtract the window width to get the left edge :

```
var left = $(document).outerWidth() - $(window).width();
$('body, html').scrollLeft(left);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I ended up going with this solution based on your help: `$('body, hmtl').animate({ scrollLeft: '+=500'}, 1000);`

Comment: I used this solution for a similar problem, and found it useful to compare the `scrollWidth` property of the element to its `width()`, like `$('selector')[0].scrollWidth - $('selector').width()`

Answer (score 5):

You actually can do it with a div ID. If you have a div like this:

```
<div id="divid" style="position: absolute; left: 9000px;">Far Right</div>
```

Then just change your `location.hash` to match:

```
location.hash = "divid";
```

The browser will take care of scrolling for you.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/B2aQF/1/

Basically, you can set the left scroll position of the body using jQuery's `scrollLeft` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').scrollLeft($(document).outerWidth()); 
});
```

You could even set the scrollLeft to a higher number than you will ever need, as it doesn't overscroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll page use `window.scrollTo`

```js
window.scrollTo(x, y)
```

- Scroll  to the maximum right

```js
window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollWidth, 0)
```

- Scroll an additional `N` pixels to the right

```js
window.scrollTo(window.pageXOffset + N, 0)
```